# CronTab(user=name) fails with TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'

Tags: python, linux, automation, cron, python-3.6

I've tried this script through "cron" but it is showing me a error like this.

```py
from crontab import CronTab

my_cron = CronTab(user='arpit')
job = my_cron.new(command='/home/hirensoni/Documents/arpit/scrapping.py')
job.minute.every(1)

my_cron.write()
```

The error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'
  File "/home/hirensoni/Documents/arpit/regularautomation.py", line 3, in <module>
    my_cron = CronTab(user='arpit')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have [`crontab`](https://pypi.org/project/crontab/#description) installed instead of [`Python-crontab`](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/). This two libraries share the same namespace.

To fix that, you can replaces the libraries:

```
pip uninstall crontab
pip install python-crontab
```

**Edit**

Also, use your real username.

Your `scrapping.py` script must be executable. It is better to use a real command, for instance `/usr/local/bin/python your_script.py`

```
from crontab import CronTab

my_cron = CronTab(user='hirensoni')
job = my_cron.new(command='/usr/local/bin/python /home/hirensoni/Documents/arpit/scrapping.py')
job.minute.every(1)

my_cron.write()
```

Comment: Now, it is raising a new error like this :- File "/home/hirensoni/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/crontab.py", line 295, in read
    raise IOError("Read crontab %s: %s" % (self.user, err))
OSError: Read crontab arpit: b"crontab:  user `arpit' unknown\n"  @Laurent

Comment: If it solved your issue, you can accept this answer. The second issue is another problem: it’s better to post a new question.

Comment: @arpit_25, "arpit" is not your username, isn't it? It is "hirensoni" ? If "arpit" is another user on the same machine, you may not have right access and/or credentials.

Comment: "arpit" is a folder name under    /home/hirensoni/Documents/arpit @Laurent

Comment: So, this is not your **username**, replace by “hirensoni”